# How does 100 1000 become 200?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, computer-science

Turn these characters into 200:

> 100 1000

Using only one bit of information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using only one bit

> We place a 1 in front to give 11001000 which is 200 in binary (hence the 'one bit of information')

Comment: Or between the first two digits ;-)